# C# curriculum in MSDN?

Tags: c#, msdn

I just got access to MSDN... is there a "learning C#" curriculum is here somewhere?

(By this i mean a set of tutorials and exercises, etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find basic tutorials [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336768.aspx). They appear to be specific to Visual Studio 2008 (.NET Framework 3.5), but you should be able to apply most of them to Visual Studio 2010 (.NET Framework 4)

Comment: I'm actually using 2008, so thats great!

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading to 2010 ASAP, but good luck in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Visual Studio 2003 tutorials here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Just keep in mind that the tutorials to which Mr. Warlow linked are specific to Visual Studio 2003.

Comment: Ah, hadn't spotted that, cheers! Edited answer accordingly.